# Closed geodesic on space diffeomorphic to $S^{2n}$ with positive sectional curvature always contains a conjugate point.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

For reference; a closed geodesic is a geodesic that is a closed loop that is smooth at the origin.

I have been stuck on this for a few days; the only theorem I have relating to even dimension has to do with orientability, so it doesn't seem like there's anything I will be able to do with that. The fact that it is an even dimensional sphere makes it seem like I may have to use the fact that there is no non-vanishing vector field, but I am not sure how to make this work.

Is it possible I can have some hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More generally, if $M$ is a Riemannian manifold of sectional curvature $\ge \kappa>0$ then every closed geodesic in $M$ has conjugate points. This is a direct corollary of the Rauch Comparison Theorem, where you compare $M$ with the 2-sphere equipped with the metric of constant curvature $=\kappa$. My favorite reference for the RCT is do Carmo's "Riemannian Geometry", see  Thm. 2.3 and Prop. 2.4, Chapter 10.

Comment: Is there any reason to specify that $M$ be a sphere, or even dimensional that simplifies the argument? It seems like in that case all you would need to do is specify that it is compact with positive sectional curvature. Perhaps the even dimensional sphere thing is a red herring?

Comment: @billybob: No, it does not simplify the proof and I regard this as just a red herring.

Comment: How is closedness of the geodesic used here? It seems that the closed geodesic could be too short to have any conjugate points?

Comment: @JohnMa: The curvature bound precludes short geodesics. :)

Comment: @JohnMa: A geodesic is a ps $R\to M$.

Comment: I am thinking of $\mathbb S^3/ \mathbb Z_n$, the closed geodesic can be as short as we want @TedShifrin. But if geodesic is here interpreted as just a mapping from $\mathbb R$, then my argument is pointless, (and then there are indeed lots of red herring in this question).

Comment: @JohnMa: Indeed, a geodesic is always interpreted as a map from the real line.